# DataTables Default Column Ordering with HTML Data Attribute

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I want to order the table by specific column with html data attribute instead of first column ascending ordering but i couldnt it.

Here my example table:

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried #1

```
<table id="example" data-order="3">
```

I tried #2

```
<table id="example" data-order="3, desc">
```

I tried #3

```
<table id="example" data-order="[[3, 'desc']]">
```

I dont want to use with jQuery like that:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  order: [[3, 'desc']]
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the issue that about quotes. Here is solution:

**Right Format with Double Quote**

```
data-order='[[3, "desc"]]'
```

**Wrong Format with Single Quote**

```
data-order="[[3, 'desc']]"
```

Comment: Good job, I discovered the answer here: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html

Comment: data-order="[[ 1, &quot;asc&quot; ]]" works too!

Answer (score 5):

Strangely, you have to define both parameters inside an array like this:

```
data-order='[[4, "asc"]]'
```

---

### Example

```js
$("#example").DataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example" data-order='[[4, "asc"]]'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: data-order="[[ 1, &quot;asc&quot; ]]" works too... Double quotes outside which is for me the 'beautiful' way ;-)